# Replace parent node if child is blank in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

There is a tbody in text XML tag which can be anywhere in XML document. and if tbody is blank i want to replace  no data available

```
            <title>Payers</title>
                <text>
                    <table border="1" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Payer Name</th>
                                <th>Policy Type</th>
                                <th>Policy Number</th>
                                <th>Effective Date</th>
                                <th>Expiration Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody />
                    </table>
                </text>
```

so output should be

```
                <title>Payers</title>
                <text>
                    no data available
                </text>
```

Comment: I want output <text>no data available</text>

Comment: See answer below

Comment: Please add to your input XML root element (similar as in my answer) as XML validation shoes error message "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use validation inside of node `text`, see XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!--perform validation in required node-->
    <xsl:template match="text">        
            <xsl:choose>
                <!--in case when tbody has some text then normally copy it-->
                <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space(//tbody/text())) &gt;0">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <!--in case when tbody has not any text node text will have text - no data available-->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;    no data available&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>                                                                  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So in case when XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title>Payers</title>
        <text>
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Payer Name</th>
                        <th>Policy Type</th>
                        <th>Policy Number</th>
                        <th>Effective Date</th>
                        <th>Expiration Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody/>
            </table>
        </text>
</root>
```

Result will be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<title>Payers</title>
<text>
    no data available
</text>
</root>
```

Hope it will help with your case.

Comment: How to give some namespace while filtering. it does not work.

Comment: @NishantMakwana In your question there is no words regarding namespaces and issue with them. Your question contains input XML and expected result  when tbody is blank - answer covers XSL how to get desired result you wrote with using validation inside all text blocks.

Comment: Yes @OF to create sample input i have not mentioned namespace, if you can provide me that, then it will be really grateful

Comment: @NishantMakwana Please see my edit. As I understood namespace you meant as "no data available" should go from new line, or am I wrong?